# How can I use ECMAScript 6 modules for front-end development?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, babeljs

I would like to use the ECMAScript 6 module system in a front-end project, so that the interdependencies of the code were more clear than simply loading "all that might be needed" up front, in the HTML.

However, having the following line in the main JavaScript file does not work:

```
import fuzLogin from 'fuzLogin'
```

The error in the browser's console is: `can't find variable: require`

The compiled code (created by Babel) is:

```
var _fuzLogin = require("fuzLogin");

var _fuzLogin2 = _interopRequireDefault(_fuzLogin);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Is ECMAScript 6 module system supposed to work, for compiled code, with WebStorm 10?

Should I maybe add some external dependency in my HTML, to provide the missing `require`?

Are there other ways I could reach a modular front-end orchestration of my JavaScript side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways that fulfil what I was looking for, in slightly different ways:

- [jspm](http://jspm.io)
- [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org)

JSPM allows on-the-fly loading of ES2015 modules, so that the transpiling happens in the browser. This is pretty awesome, really, and something I wasn't expecting.

In addition, JSPM also provides traditional build tools for doing the bundling for production.

But I actually chose to go with Rollup.

Rollup gathers all kinds of build systems together, and is based on ES2015 packaging, providing what I was after. Most important for me were the brilliant blog posts by Jason Lengstorf (just 1 and 2 weeks old, btw) that walk one through the whole practical setup.

### References:

- [jspm-trial](https://github.com/akauppi/jspm-trial) (GitHub) repo that I did, experimenting these things
- [Smaller, More Efficient JavaScript Bundling Using Rollup](https://code.lengstorf.com/learn-rollup-js/) (blog, Aug 2016)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're babel configuration is set up to use `commonjs` that transpiles with `require` (requirejs)... so, in order to work with that configuration you need to include requirejs: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Thanks, that's a good pointer. Unfortunately even after adding `require.min.js` I get: Module name "fuzLogin" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]). Also, the transpiled output of the module I'm trying to load does not look requirejs to me.

Comment: That's happen because babel is just a transpiler but doesn't resolve your dependencies... I suggest you to use `webpack` and put babel as a webpack loader... https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Comment: I might. Or I just play lazy and let time pass. I do like ES6 module syntax and think eventually it will become de facto. Now it's still an extra, unneeded friction for me. Other parts of ES6 pay benefits already now.